# Need help importing custom icons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to import custom icons from Fluttericons.com. I get a box with an X within it instead of the icon as shown in the image. I have included my `pubspec.yaml` and dart file that is given from Fluttericons.com.

[image: Screenshot of bad icons]

[image: Workspace screenshot]

This is the Fluttericons.com file given to me. I have tried to remove the `_kFontPkg` and that did not work.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MyIcons {
  MyIcons._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'MyIcons';
  static const _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData access_alarm = IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

```yaml
name: MyGymPro
description: Flutter fitness application

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_icons:
  percent_indicator: "^2.1.1"
  pedometer: ^1.0.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  shared_preferences: any
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.4.0
  decimal: ^0.3.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.4
  mime: ^0.9.6+3
  fluttertoast: ^4.0.0


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
   - family: MyIcons
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/MyIcons.ttf

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Also, I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm also running into the same issue. Tried restarting the emulator, created a new emulator, restarted studio, restarted entire machine etc. Nothing works. It shows a rectangle shape only.

Answer (score 1):

check where you keep the font file,

- asset: fonts/MyIcons.ttf

maybe you save it in

- asset: **assets**/fonts/MyIcons.ttf

if your min sdk not 2.12.0, i mean not supported null safety, remove
non null safety at this line `static const? _kFontPkg = null;`. not recommended this.

and then if icon not show just blank, unistall your app from emulator, and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add a dependency you should make sure that you have shutdown and restart your emulator.

Comment: what is your exit code when you save your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: exit code 0, there is no error in the debug console and everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Tried restarting and even tried with new emulator. Nothing works. Any other idea?